# Oracle SQL Queries - Change Field Value

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I change field value with my query?
I would like to see “TR” when it is ‘TÜRKEI’ in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM LAND WHERE LNDNR_LAND = '111';

D    XXX    01/01/0001    111    TÜRKEI
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select col1,col2,...., case when colN ='TÜRKEI' then 'TR' else colN end as colN
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column name is `col` and you

you can use SQL Standard `case`:

```
select t.*, case when col = 'TÜRKEI' then 'TR' else col end as col_new
from your_table t;
```

or Oracle specific `decode`:

```
select t.*, decode(col, 'TÜRKEI', 'TR', col) as col_new
from your_table t;
```

If you want to update the table with the value, you can simple update

```
update your_table
set col = 'TR'
where col = 'TÜRKEI';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value in database then you have use **Update** statement.
The SQL **UPDATE** statement is used to update **existing records** in the tables.

e.g

```
update tablename
set column1 = value
where condition;
```